# Integral $\int\frac{1}{\sin^3(x)\cos(x)}\,dx$

Tags: integration

I have a problem with this integral:
$$\int\frac{1}{\sin^3(x)\cos(x)}\,dx$$
Please help me how to do this.

Comment: I tried but i dont have idea how to do this exaple

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\int\frac{1}{\sin^3(x)\cos(x)}\,dx$$
$$\int\frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\sin^3(x)\cos(x)}\,dx$$
$$\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}\,dx+\int\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^3(x)}\,dx$$
$$\int\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2} \sin(2x)}\,dx+\int\frac{\cot(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\,dx$$
*First integral:*
$$\int\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2} \sin(2x)}\,dx$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
t=2x   \\
\frac{dt}{2}=dx  \\
\end{array} $$
\int\frac{dt}{\sin(t)}$$
$$\ln\left\lvert\tan\frac{t}{2}\right\rvert+C$$
*Now we have:* 
$$\ln\left\vert\tan(x)\right\rvert+C$$
*Second integral:*
$$\int\frac{\cot(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\,dx$$
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
t=\cot(x)   \\
-dt=\frac{dx}{\sin^2(x)}  \\
\end{array} $$
$$-\int t\, dt=-\frac{1}{2} \cot^2(x)+C$$
*Sum up:* 
$$\int\frac{1}{\sin^3(x)\cos(x)}\,dx=\ln\left\lvert\tan(x)\right\rvert-\frac{1}{2}\cot^2(x)+C$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $\cos x$ and do the substitution $t=\sin x$:
$$
\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin^3x\cos^2x}\,dx=
\int\frac{1}{t^3(1-t^2)}\,dt
$$
With partial fractions it's easy, now.

Comment: It becomes $\frac{1}{t^3 (1-t^2)} = \frac{1}{t^3}+\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{2 (t+1)}-\frac{1}{2 (t-1)}$, so it's really easy.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{1}{\sin^3(x)\cos(x)}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\csc^3(x)\sec(x)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\left(\cot^2(x)+1\right)\csc(x)\sec(x)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\left(\cot(x)\csc^2(x)+\csc(x)\sec(x)\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\csc(x)\sec(x)\space\text{d}x+\int\cot(x)\csc^2(x)\space\text{d}x=$$

---

For the integrand $\csc(x)\sec(x)$, substitute $u=\tan(x)$ and $\text{d}u=\sec^2(x)\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}u+\int\cot(x)\csc^2(x)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\ln\left|u\right|+\int\cot(x)\csc^2(x)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\ln\left|\tan(x)\right|+\int\cot(x)\csc^2(x)\space\text{d}x=$$

---

For the integrand $\cot(x)\csc^2(x)$, substitute $s=\cot(x)$ and $\text{d}s=-\csc^2(x)\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\ln\left|\tan(x)\right|+\int s\space\text{d}s=$$
$$\ln\left|\tan(x)\right|+\frac{s^2}{2}+\text{C}=$$
$$\ln\left|\tan(x)\right|+\frac{\cot^2(x)}{2}+\text{C}$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $1$ as $sin^2x+cos^2x$ $$\int\frac{1}{sinxcosx}dx+\int\frac{cosx}{sin^3x}dx $$ for second term use substitution $sinx=t$. For first one again write $1$ as $sin^2x+cos^2x$. Which gives $$\int tanxdx+\int cotx dx $$
Evaluate these by substitution $cosx=t$ and $sinx=t$ respectively.